# Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String Error

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, int, varchar

Hi when I run my code I get this error:

> Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int32 and System.String

I need a way to allow int and varchar but cannot think of a solution for it. I understand that it is to do with the fact my id option is an integer but cannot think of a solution and would really appreciate your help.

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim FilterExpression As String = String.Concat(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, " LIKE " + "'%{0}%'")
    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Clear()
    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add(New ControlParameter(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "TextBox1", "Text"))
    SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = FilterExpression



End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: something somewhere needs to be converted.  Either parse your int or cast/convert it to a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, LIKE is a string operator.

I would suggest that you need to reconsider your design, but if you're determined to search for numbers with "LIKE", you should have a trigger populate a varchar() version of the field in the table.

Comment: Using LIKE for numeric strings would have perverse consequences like "1" matching "1", or "12", or "3010", or "1000000000000".    Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Yeah, this is not `JavaScript` where type coercion results in what Curt said.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL Server are you using?  Depending on the version in the SPROC or TSQL you can run bountiful commands on your data to manipulate it like you may need it to be.  A great example would be.

```
    Select TRY_CONVERT(STRING, 12065) is Null
```